# Camera rotation with interpolation

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, interpolation, quaternions

I have an object that rotates on the y axis with the "Mouse X" input and a video camera that through a slerp quaternion should follow the rotation of the object.
Unfortunately, when I rotate the object with fast mouse movements, the rotation of the slerp camera stops as if it hits a wall and does not follow that of the object.
Without quaternion slerp it works following the object but I need to do it with the interpolation.

rotation object (in LateUpdate:

```
float rot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * speedrotation;
transform.Rotate(0, rot, 0);
```

rotation camera (in LateUpdate):

```
var rot = Quaternion.Slerp(camera.transform.rotation, object.rotation, speed_rot * Time.deltaTime);
camera.transform.position = object.transform.position + rot;
camera.transform.LookAt(object.transform.position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try EulerAngles instead! That is better option for make camera controller!

```
Simple Code:
Vector3 currentCameraEulers;
float rotationDPI = 7f; // I didn't remeber how to call better this thing

void Update(){
float cameraX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * rotationDPI;
if(cameraX != 0f){
currentCameraEulers = new Vector3(0, cameraX, 0);
transform.eulerAngles += currentCameraEulers;
}
}
```

That should work completely fine.

Comment: I think you should do rotation camera (in LateUpdate) easy too with EulerAngles.

Comment: I tried but nothing and I understood that it happens because the speed of the object that follows was too high. The camera that uses lerp and therefore moves late suffered this, I had to lower the speed of the object followed.